# Databricks extension vscode - Socket is closed

Tags: proxy, databricks, vscode-extensions, azure-databricks

I cannot connect to Databricks using the vscode extension. 
 I get the error message:
`Databricks cannot login: Socket is closed`.

I'm behind a company webproxy but setting `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` in powershell does not work.

Im on Databricks Extension v1.1.1, vscode 1.79 and Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally solved it and the issue was that vscode did not have `proxySupport` enabled by default. Adding these two rows in my vscode `settings.json` did the trick:

```
"http.proxySupport":"on",
"http.proxy": "http://<company-webproxy>:<port>",
```

After lots of searching this is where I found the solution:
https://gist.github.com/PSJoshi/0831f635f9f5a7b9c602b80fbbf3125a#setting-up-proxy-support

However, in my case I didn't have to include user/passwd in the proxy-address.